# How to get perl json access hash reference

Tags: json, perl

I am trying to get remote host value which is remotehost . I decoded the json  and able to get $name and $id values. but getting

> Bad index while coercing array into hash while accessing 'remote -> host value which is remotehost.

```
 my $json input is
  [
 {
    "auth":{
        "req": "1234",
        "link": "http://localhost" 
    },
    "host": "localhost",
    "name": "mytest",
    "remote": [
        {
            "host": "remotehost",
            "name": "remotetest"
        }
    ]
 }
]

#My code 
use JSON qw( decode_json );
use Data::Dumper;
my $list = decode_json($json) ;
my @array = @{$list};
foreach(@array)
          {
          my %obj = %{$_};
          my $id = $obj{'auth'}{'link'};
          my $name = $obj{'name'};
          my $remotehost = $obj{'auth'}->{'remote'}{'host'}; #getting error
          }
```

Comment: Try `$obj{'remote'}{'host'}`

Comment: Hi AnFi, Thanks for your response. I tried that. I am getting 'Bad index while coercing array into hash' error.

Comment: Try `$obj{'remote'}[0]{'host'}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 "remote": [
        {
            "host": "remotehost",
            "name": "remotetest"
        }
    ]
```

This bit is an array of objects (hashes in Perl). You cannot *coerce* it. You need to access the 1st element.

```
#   A
#   |           B    
#   |           |    C
#   |           |    |
$obj{'remote'}->[0]->{'host'}
```

Note there's no `auth` in this, because that's on the same level as `remote` (marked as A).

```
 {
    "auth" : {
        "req": "1234",
        "link": "http://localhost" 
    },
    "host" : "localhost",
    "name" : "mytest",

    // A
    "remote" : [ // B

        { // C
            "host": "remotehost",
            "name": "remotetest"
        }
    ]
 }
```